# java - Pausing all running threads for some time

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, database-trigger, thread-sleep

For instance consider the below scenario.

*App1: I have a multiple-threaded java app, which enters a lot of files in DB.*

*App2: when i access the DB using some other app, its slow in fetching results.*

So when both apps work simultaneously, it takes great time for DB fetching results on the front-end app2.

**Here, i want to pause all transactions(threads) on App1 for some 'x min' time. Considering a trigger has already been installed when app 2 is being used. So when App2 is idle, App1 will resume as if nothing happened. Please list some or one best approach to achieve this**

```
Map<Thread, StackTraceElement[]> threads = Thread.getAllStackTraces();
    for (Map.Entry<Thread, StackTraceElement[]> entry : threads.entrySet()) {
        entry.getKey().sleep();
    }
```

This didn't worked well.

Comment: Please read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) - asking for list of subjectively good approaches is both too broad and opinionated for the SO format. There are probably other discussion-focused websites that this type of question is more suited to.

Comment: If you want something that works like a timer, why not use a Timer (java.util.Timer)? It can be scheduled for one-time execution, or for repeated execution at regular intervals.

Comment: Or just put a Thread.sleep in your Thread, that is executed when a flag is set to true (so the flag can also be changed from outside of the Thread, if you want that)

Comment: @billbrinck: by Thread.sleep() i can pause just current instance thread.
i want to pause all threads. By fetching all running threads and then triggering .sleep() didn't actually worked.

Comment: But only the Threads that you have created, right?

Comment: @Vinnie i corrected my question, i just want to pause and resume all the treads

Comment: @billbrinck correct mate. Its an event driven approach, where i want to pause all threads.

Comment: So what if you store your threads in a list/array create a method pauseAllThreads, that loops over all the Threads, sets a pauseFlag to true and then Thread.sleep when the flag is set to true in all Threads?

Comment: @billbrinck already tried, Thread.getAllStackTraces() - this gives all the threads, i tried .sleep() in forEach but didn't worked. Also i added a little code segment for clarity.

Comment: @KanishkPipariya Please check out my answer below. Maybe something like this could work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to try:

```
private List<PausableThread> threads = new ArrayList<PausableThread>();

private void pauseAllThreads()
{
    for(PausableThread thread : this.threads)
    {
        thread.pause();
    }
}
```

And your Thread class will be something like this:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread implements PausableThread
{

private boolean isPaused = false;

@Override
public void pause()
{
    this.isPaused = true;
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
    {
        // Do your work...

        // Check if paused
        if(this.isPaused)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

And the PausableThread interface:

```
public interface PausableThread
{
    void pause();
}
```

Comment: I got the basic idea from it. That worked, thank you mate.

Answer (score 0):

Posting a solution answer, for my scenario.

I created a global flag and used it as a switch.

SO now, before DB interaction i just added a condition [in various functions where threads were performing variety of jobs, this solved the instance issue i was worried about]

```
if(isFlagChecked){thread.sleep(someDefinedTime);}

wait here if flag is true

continue with business logic...[db transacts here]
```

So, my issue was solved with just this, although it wouldn't pause thread running in intermediate state, which is kind of a good thing - one less trouble.

Parallel, in my trigger function - i checked for the elapsed time and changed the flag to false after desired time has passed. Check code skeleton below.

```
@async 
void pause() // triggered by parallel running app when required
{
   isFlagChecked=true;
   resumeTime=new Date(timeInMillis + (someDefinedTime)) // resume time to switch flag condition
   while (true) {
      if (new Date().compareTo(resumeTime) > 0) 
         isFlagChecked=false;
    }
}
```

Tried and tested, all running well, the performance improved significantly [least for my scenario].